# Qt creator : create an APK compatible with multiple ABIs?

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

When building a Qt application on android, you have to choose whether you want to use ARM abi or x86 abi. Is it possible to create an APK compatible with **both** ABIs, and how ?

If I'm correct, the APK built by Qt Creator has a subfolder libs/ containing all the shared libraries required by the JNI. Depending on what you build, libs/ contains either *"armeabi-v7a"* or *"x86"* subfolder with the correct files.
How can I have an APK containing **both** subfolders, such that all Android devices can run the APK ? I tried by modifiying the APK myself (since it's a plain .zip), but it messed up signatures etc.

Or am I doomed to publish to Google Play with two APKs ?

Comment: You are doomed for the time being https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664115/produce-an-apk-for-multiple-architectures-for-qt-projects

Comment: Dammit. I guess I'll read some docs about multi-APKs apps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that work (at lest for me).

- Build the APKs (e.g.armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a) separate. Sign the APKs in the Buil APK Step in QtCreator in order to build a release - APK (w/o debug server).
- Use ZIP tool (e.g. 7zip) to open the unsigned **arm-v7a release** APK and copy the **"/lib/armeabi-v7a"** folder to the unsigned **arm64-v8a release APK** (the unsigned APK is created by QTC before signing).
- Run **zipalign 4 on the combined apk** and sign the aligned APK with **apksigner**.
- Done

The whole process can be programmed in a cmd or bat file.